# Connect ContactForm Wordpress to Another Database in another IP

Tags: database, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a Wordpress site in a Machine, for example: www.mydomain1.cl IP 192.12.34.56.  I want to insert data from my Contact Form 7 to a database instead of sending email.  I have been able to do it if both databases are on the same IP with this line:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('user1','password1','databasename','localhost');
```

But now I want to do the same but instead of inserting in the same server with same IP, I want to insert data in another IP (165.22.22.22), example: www.myhost.cl, I have tried as follows:

```
$mydb = new wpdb('user1','password1','databasename','165.22.22.22');
$mydb = new wpdb('user1','password1','databasename','myhost.cl');
$mydb = new wpdb('user1','password1','databasename','www.myhost.cl');
```

In 165.22.22.22 I have created a user like this, but the data is not being inserted:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON databasename TO 'user1'@'192.12.34.56' IDENTIFIED BY 'password1';
```

This is the function at functions.php in my Wordpress:

```
function contactform7_before_send_mail($form_to_DB)
{
    //set your db details
    $mydb = new wpdb('user1','password1','databasename','localhost');
    //$mydb = new wpdb('user1','password1','databasename','165.22.22.22');
    //$mydb = new wpdb('user1','password1','databasename','myhost.cl');
    $mydb = new wpdb('user1','password1','databasename','www.myhost.cl');

    $form_to_DB = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if ( $form_to_DB ) 
    $formData         = $form_to_DB->get_posted_data();
    $campoEmail       = $formData['campoEmail'];
    $mydb->insert( 'important_emails', array( 'email_para'                   =>$campoEmail
                                            ), array('%s') );
}
```

Could anyone give me some idea, help, please? I really appreciate it